# Correct design for using the same data for different views

Tags: android, android-fragments, caching, android-viewpager, android-gridview

I am new in the corporate world & from design perspective please correct me if I am doing something wrong here

I am fetching images from Flickr API.

GOAL: Show these images in two different type of view, grid view and listview. Which can be switch through the slide.

So I am using a View pager with two fragments and both of these fragments has separate listeners. So when the response came from Flickr both of these listeners are notified.

In my opinion, this saves two times calling of REST API, but I am looking for even more efficient design or flow through which

- Using single listener
- Rest API should be called once
- Result should be store (Just in ArrayList) and share to both of views
- May not choosing two separate  fragments
- Avoid creating Adapter object two times
- Image should be stored in cache

Any tweak or suggestions will be helpful a lot, please comment if you don't understand any part or whole question.

Answer (score 0):

For above problem, the tweaking you are thinking is almost right. Other than below:

What I believe you must create two different adapters to have more control over different views. For example, you might want to show with scale type crop center for an image in list view but scale type center inside for an image in grid view. There might be the different type of thing you may want to perform. So, it's a good practice to make two different adapters, to make the code more manageable.

Again the same goes for the fragment, see if actions in both the fragments are same or can be done with single variable passing. Then only go with a single fragment.

Rest of the things are perfect.

Comment: It would be great if we can use only one listener to do this. I understand your point that we should use two adapters but as the view is static, can't we use single adapter with getViewType ?

Comment: you can go that way, but you need to send a variable to adapter to decide which view to use.